# captcha code usage in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, captcha

how to insert the "captcha code" and its validation process in vb asp.net.... i have searched every were but i could not get its code..

atleast tel me is it possible to do so or not..
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Google result:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx

Searched for "captcha asp.net"